# Profile url error in Buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I have installed buddypress on localhost. It is working fine. The problem is when currently logged in user view other user's profile page then it displays wrong url. It is currently displaying currently logged in user url but it should display displayed user url.

Can anyone explain this and give the solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Apache. Have u modified "Permalinks". Is .htaccess set up properly?
Are you having problems accessing other pages?
What version of LAMPP/MAMPP/XAMPP/WAMPP are u using?
What version of BP and WP?